# How to filter rows for multiple string/words

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, ms-office, office365

I'm completing a project for work that requires me to sift through a spreadsheet of 20,000+ different accounts of Churches/religious buildings. However, there are random small businesses and people with the last name "Church" or "Iglesia" mixed into the spreadsheet that I need to remove, as their account info is useless. The only useful information I'm provided is the account name.

So far, what I've been doing is filtering the account names column by keywords that will result in only churches showing up (like "ministry" or "Methodist", for example). Then I created a new column next to the account names column. If the account is a real church, I put a 1 and if not, I leave it blank. I will then filter for blanks and delete accounts that aren't churches. However, this is time-consuming and a very inaccurate process, as my list of keywords used to filter accounts is not exhaustive of all church names.

Is there at least a way to filter all account names by a list of keywords at once instead of having to do it two words at a time through "custom filter"

Any ideas on how I can delete non-church accounts more efficiently?

Comment: I think you'll have to come up with some other means of identifying how "Lutheran Church" is different from "Sam Church", unless your scan looks for "church" then also looks for a list of keywords in the same string. The problem is that it will be difficult to make that list of keywords comprehensive. Unless there's another field that helps you identify organizations separately from people.

Comment: The Advanced Filter will handle multiple keywords.

Answer (score 1):

To check each entry against a list of words you can use a formula like the one shown below.  It will return the number of words matched.

It's an array formula, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering it

[image]